# using a while loop for user to input multiple int and find the max and min

Tags: java

so my homework question is prompt user a series of integers and find the max and min of those integer. Use a loop and -99 to break loop.Below is my code but my question is that is there a shorter way for this? feel free to comment and i appreciate your time reading this.

```
  Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
  int num1,num2,max,min;
  System.out.print("enter a number: ");
  num1=input.nextInt();
  System.out.print("enter another number: ");
  num2=input.nextInt();
  max=Math.max(num1,num2);
  min=Math.min(num1,num2);


  while (num2!=-99){
      System.out.print("enter a number or -99 to stop: ");
      num2=input.nextInt();
      if(num2!=-99){
      max=Math.max(max,num2);
      min=Math.min(min,num2);
      }

  }
  System.out.println("largest is: "+max);
  System.out.println("Smallest is: "+min);
```

Comment: You might want to consider posting working code on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. StackOverflow is more about actual problems.

Comment: You don't need to ask for the first two numbers upfront.  It can all be in the loop.  Just set min initially to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (yes, MAX value) and max to `Integer.MIN_VALUE' and loop alone will take care of everything.

Comment: @KevinAnderson what if the person then does not enter a number? It would say the max value the user entered would be `Integer.MIN_VALUE` which would be wrong

Comment: Good point @Mitchel0022,, for absolute rigor the case where the user entered no number at all (i.e., entered -99 as the first number) should be be recognized and handled specially.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok So after working on this. I finally did it. It does have a small bug, but I really don't wanna fix it so if anyway wants to edit this then be my guest.

```
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int studentNum = 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> calc = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    while (studentNum <= 100) {

        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        calc.add(input.nextInt());

        studentNum += 1;

        if (input.nextInt() == -99) {
            break;
        }

    }

    int min = Collections.min(calc);
    int max = Collections.max(calc);

    for (int i = 0; i < calc.size(); i++) {
        int number = calc.get(i);
        if (number < min)
            min = number;
        if (number > max)
            max = number;
    }

    System.out.println("Max is " + max);
    System.out.println("Min is " + min);
```

This does exactly what you want. However, there was a problem checking for the exit signal.

```
 if (input.nextInt() == -99) {
            break;
        }
```

this checks if the userInput is equal to -99 then stops the program and calculates and prints out the min and max. However the tiny bug is that it will first ask for your number to add to the array list and then it will ask again for the userInput to check if its equal to -99. But overall it does exactly what you want.

Hope this helped.

*EDIT* I will work on it later and find a way to fix that bug if no one else knows.

Comment: Is this kinda what you wanted? because if this helped you can help me by pressing that checkmark next to my question. would mean a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You check for the condition of `num2 != -99` twice, remember the first rule of programming, do not repeat yourself

You could save some lines by checking for min and max before asking for the next input. This way you do not need to check if `num2 != -99` inside the while loop

Answer (score 0):

Your code has one minor bug and can be slightly optimised. Things you might want to consider:

- What happens (and what should happen) when the user types `-99` as the second number?
- Do you necessarily need to have at least 2 numbers? Wouldn't one be enough for the program to exit gracefully? The first number would then be both `min` and `max`.
- Can you re-order your code lines so that the duplicated `(num2!=-99)` is not necessary anymore?

Pro questions:

- What happens if the user types in some letters? How can you handle that case?
- What happens if the user types in a super high number (bigger than the maximal integer)?
- What happens if the user presses `enter` without typing any number?

Nitpicking:

- Using `+` to concatenate strings and numbers is a bad idea because it's hard to remember where it works and where it doesn't.

  Better look into [String.valueOf(int i)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(int)) and [String.format(String format, Object... args)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...))
- Look up [Google's Java Coding Style](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html) for formatting your code in best readable way. In many editors you can automatically apply the style. It describes things like where to use spaces or what to indent.